# Using remote validation with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a remote validation as follows:

```
[Remote("CheckValue", "Validate", ErrorMessage="Value is not valid")]
public string Value { get; set; }
```

I am using ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET 5) and it seems Remote is not available.
Does anyone know how to do this with ASP.NET CORE?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The RemoteAttribute is part of ASP.Net MVC Core:

- If you are using RC1, it is in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc` namespace. See [`RemoteAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.ViewFeatures/RemoteAttribute.cs) in github.
- After the renaming planned in RC2, it will be in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace. See [`RemoteAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures/RemoteAttribute.cs) in github.

For example, in RC1 create a new MVC site with authentication. Then update the generated `LoginViewModel` with a dummy remote validation calling a method in the home controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Remote("Foo", "Home", ErrorMessage = "Remote validation is working")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

If you create that dummy method in the home controller and set a breakpoint, you will see it is hit whenever you change the email in the login form:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    ...

    public bool Foo()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right ... I was looking at System.Component.DataAnnotations and I even went that library source in Github. Of course it is in Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc. Thanks!

Comment: The links are broken

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, the documentation is there and available [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation). In a nutshell you just need to decorate your view model's property with the following:

```
    [Remote(action: "Foo", controller: "Bar", ErrorMessage = "Remote validation is working")]
    [Required]        
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Then create an action (named 'Foo' in this example) in the controller (named 'Bar' in this example) and add your logic there:

```
  [AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(string name)
  {
      bool exists = await this.Service.Exists(name);
      if (exists)
          return Json(data: false);
      else
          return Json(data: true);
  }
```

Final note: the Remote attribute is in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc` namespace.