# Modify Asp.Net Core MVC data annotations within the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, data-annotations, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am building an application using ASP.NET Core MVC and I have the requirement of having dynamic Data annotations for some fields. For instance, the data annotation `[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long", MinimumLength = 3)]` 
I am using on an input type text, in some cases when the page is open must be 3 in other cases it must be 6.

How can I achieve this dynamically?

Comment: Does the validation need to be handled with real time validation, or can it be a response from the server? Also, where are the dynamic values coming from?

Comment: @WillRay Yes, it has to be real time validation and the values are coming from the database. I intend to have editable fields where I can set the maximum and minimum string length  and save it in to the database

Comment: Your easiest solution might be to use the [RemoteAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033022/using-remote-validation-with-asp-net-core), and use the injection for controllers to check the length.

Comment: @WillRay thanks! I haven´t tried it yet but this seems like a solution. I´ll write an answer once I try it and works

Comment: I can create a sample demonstrating it's implementation in an answer, if that would be helpful for you?

Comment: if you can that would be of great help, thanks!