# how to show all the errors on a page in one shot (submit button) by client side validation in mvc .net core

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have a page with many required fields. So when I click submit button required validation is firing for the first field then the second then the third and so on...

What I need to do here is , When I click on submit I have to show all errors on a page in one shot.
My requirement is to achieve this only by validating client side.

I am using an .Net core MVC application.
Below is the screenshot of my page
[image]
Can I achieve this.. Please help me..
Thanks !!

Comment: Create a custom java-script or jquery function for your requirement and add [event handler](https://api.jquery.com/click) to catch the submit button click.

Comment: @shalitha your idea is good, but how can I get all the fields in page which are required and throw the validation

Comment: Please get an idea from [http://jsfiddle.net/aog1tgz1/](http://jsfiddle.net/aog1tgz1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we need to add the JQuery,jquery.validate & jquery.validate.unobtrusive in our views.

```
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validation.unobtrusive/3.2.6/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

Then in View add required `data-*` attributes like:

```
<label for="Name">Name</label>
<input type="text" data-val="true" data-val-length="Length must be between 10 to 25" data-val-length-max="25" data-val-length-min="10" data-val-required="Please enter the name" id="Name" name="Name" value="" />
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
<br />
```

You could see that it has added the several attributes starting with `data-*`.

The `data-*` attributes are part of the `HTML5`, which allow us the add extra information (metadata) to the HTML element.

The `Javascript` unobtrusive library reads the `data-val` attributes and performs the client side validation in the browser when the user submits the form. These Validations are done before the form is sent over an HTTP. If there is a validation error, then the request will not be sent.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an idea to do your job using jquery custom validation.Please refer my solution.

1. Add custom style class to your required fields.

   Example :

   ```
    <input type="text" class="req-cls" >
   ```
2. Write Jquery function to Check Validation

   ```
     $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#btn1').click(function (e) {
                   var isValid = true;
                   $('.req-cls').each(function () {
                          if ($.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                               isValid = false;
                               $(this).css({
                                   "border": "1px solid red",
                                   "background": "#FFCECE"
                               });
                           }
                           else {
                               $(this).css({
                                    "border": "",
                                    "background": ""
                               });
                           }
                    });

                    if (isValid == false)
                          e.preventDefault();

          });
     });
   ```

See Example here : https://jsfiddle.net/Shalitha/q2n8L9wg/24/

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line in your .cshtml

```
<div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
  <ul>
   <li style="display: none;"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: does this div should be before beginform or where this div should be placed

Comment: @Meena you can try by placing it  before beginform

Answer (score 0):

Since you need client side we are talking about JS. But with razor you can validate a few results using the model annotations. For example let's say you have this object.

```
public class UserCreationVO
{
   [Required]
   [StringLength(255)]
   public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

Now what you need to do in your frontend (meaning your .cshtml file) is to tell asp.net to use this properties to validate. So for example:

```
@model UserCreationVO
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="UserName" />
    <span asp-validation-for="UserName"></span>
</form>
```

As you can see above using asp-for is a great way to create validations using your models. Be careful you must pass as a model the object you want to validate. The **asp-for** tag shows a model property. So you can't pass it in a Viewbag or something. This produces some automatic html and js for you and handles it.

Furthermore you should always validate the result nevertheless in the controller. Because client side validation is for performance reasons and user experience and doesn't offer any kind of security:

```
public IActionResult CreateUser(UserCreationVO user)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
     return your_error;
}
```

Last but not least: **You must include the JQuery unobtrusive validation library**. Furthermore if you have some extra requirements like checking if a username exists (Which can't be done without contacting the server) then you can use the `[Remote]` attribute.

More info and reading about front-end validation with razor: [here](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/validation)

How to use a remote attribute: [Using remote validation with ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033022/using-remote-validation-with-asp-net-core)

EDIT:

So generally I advise to use models and create them. As you say policy is required in one form but not in another. What you should do to have a maintanable code where you simply change the attribute of your model and the validation happens you need to create a different VO. For example:

```
public class CreatePolicyVO
{
  [Required]
   public string PolicyNumber {get; set;}
}
```

And another object for example updating:

```
public class UpdatePolicyVO
{

   public string PolicyNumber {get; set;}
}
```

Because you also need to validate them in the controller. So passing a different object allows you to use ModelState.IsValid and other MVC and razor features. Generally if a field is required in one case and not in another then you need a different model.

Comment: I cannot use DataAnnotations approach because  PolicyNumber could be required in one form but not mandatory in another.. So I have to do it by validating client side

Comment: I found the solution and posted my answer. That worked like a charm form my requirement.